# How do I make my plugin load before the headers are output so I can redirect wordpress?

Tags: plugins, headers

I wrote some code, that helps secure my clients files, and added it to wordpresses function file. however, whenever updates come in, it obviously overwrites my function.

So I wanted to create it as a plugin.

However, I keep getting this error:

```
PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by...
```

So I need to execute my code, BEFORE wordpress sends the headers.

How do I do that?

Thanks,
Richard

Update. Okay, here is the code, I changed the tags though, but same premise...

```
<?php 
/*
 * Plugin Name: My WP Plugin
 * Plugin URI: http://www.example.com/plugins
 * Description: My Plugin
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: My Name
 * Author URI: http://www.example.com/
*/

function somebit_init() {
    $_permaStruc = get_option('permalink_structure');
    if($_permaStruc != "") {
        if($_GET['dl']) {
            header("Location: http://google.com");
            exit;
        } else if($_GET['download']) {
            header("Location: http://google.com");
            exit;
        }
    }
}
add_action('init', 'somebit_init');
?>
```

I'm still getting the "PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by..." error.

Do you see why? I cannot find it. maybe I did something wrong that I cannot see.

Richard

Comment: How are you calling your code? What action/filter are you hooking into?

Comment: @czerspalace, I updated the post above, it now shows the entire code, I have just updated, but still having a error.

Comment: The even crazier thing is, that even if I just put the check and do not do anything, no action in the if statement, I still get the headers already sent error. But if I'm not printing anything to the page, or trying to set a header, or trying to redirect, why would it get that error? I don't get it.

Comment: Now, I ONLY added the function:

`code` function somebit_init() {/* Do Nothing */ }
add_action('template_redirect', 'somebit_init');
`code`
and I still get the error.

Comment: What if you remove the  `?>` that is after the `add_action`

Comment: @czerspalace that made the page load, but the code does not seem to be executing... does not the `?>` have to be there for PHP to process?

Comment: @czerspalace, okay, I added some test code, it is executing inside the if statement, but if I put a redirect in there, it is giving me this error still: `PHP Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/username/public_html/hvac/wp-content/plugins/My-Security-Plugin/my_securit‌​y_security.php:1) in /home/username/public_html/hvac/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 876` not sure why. if it is being executed with the `init` it should be before headers, right?

Comment: @czerspalace actually, it is showing that error even if I just have it echo a message like "nothing here to see"... then exit wordpress. I still see that cannot modify headers. What is trying to modify the headers though? If the init is executed before headers are sent?

Comment: If you see here in the [Codex](https://make.wordpress.org/core/handbook/coding-standards/php/#remove-trailing-spaces), removing the closing php tag is preferred. So what happens if you remove the `?>` and then run the echo statement? Or is that what you tried?

Comment: I did remove it, and it did not fix it. Still it puts the error in the error log that I showed you above about not being able to modify the headers, even though nothing is trying to modify any headers.

Comment: Do you have any other plugins running? If so, have you tried deactivating those to see if they are causing the issue?

Comment: @czerspalace, no other plugins activated. I am testing this on a site I have not setup yet, that is a demo site anyways... so I can play with it and it does not matter if it is broke yet since I have not set it up, so I don't show it to anyone... Not sure why it would do this.

Comment: In your theme's functions.php file is there also a closing `?>`, and if so, what happens if you remove it then try your code?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use header redirect instead of wp_redirect?

Answer (score 6):

The correct hook to use is `template_redirect` which allows you to have the necessary info available to do checks while also early enough to actually redirect. As per the example on the codex page:

```
function my_page_template_redirect()
    {
    if( is_page( 'goodies' ) && ! is_user_logged_in() )
    {
        wp_redirect( home_url( '/signup/' ) );
        exit();
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_page_template_redirect' );
```

Codex page here - [template_redirect](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect)

Answer (score 3):

How about using this action?
[Codex Link - send_headers action](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/send_headers)

```
add_action( 'send_headers', 'add_redirect_header' );
function add_redirect_header() {
    header( 'Location: http://www.google.com' );
}
```

Comment: would use `wp_headers` hook so you can modify the headers before sent, with the WP function `wp_redirect()`

Answer (score 2):

use `add_action('init', 'your_function');`

or any action hook before headers are sent: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Comment: `template_redirect` can be used if the function handling the redirect depends on WP being loaded

Comment: @karpstrucking I tried that, same error. "PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by..." the files it says already sent them, is the code I updated on the original post... but I never started any headers.

Comment: when does this error appear, when you try to activate the plugin? can you post the whole error, including file path info

Comment: It appears in the error log. On the wordpress site, I get a blank page. nothing.

Here is the whole error string, only changed the username in the path...

`code`"[13-Jan-2015 19:16:35 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/username/public_html/hvac/wp-content/plugins/My-Security-Plugin/my_security_security.php:1) in /home/username/public_html/hvac/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 876"`code`

Comment: the plugin is activated. it did say that there were 3 unexpected characters output when activated, but it stayed active and no errors and the page loads, but the error happens when I put the dl=filename.zip or anything with ?dl= in the url.

Answer (score 0):

Your checks, `if($_GET['dl'])` and `else if($_GET['download'])` are throwing `Undefined index:` errors, and that appears to be causing a headers issue with your My Security Plugin.

Try changing it to:

```
function somebit_init() {
    $_permaStruc = get_option('permalink_structure');
    if($_permaStruc != "") {
        if( !empty($_GET['dl'])) {
            header("Location: http://google.com");
            exit;
        } else if( !empty($_GET['download'])) {
            header("Location: http://google.com");
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a function I used to check if a non logged in user is trying to enter directly in custom page (only for users), it check if someone entered certain page.

Even makes a second check if the main cookies are created (useful to avoid undefined index errors)

```php
    function validate_sesion() {
    if ((is_page('something'))||(is_singular('something'))) {
        if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
            wp_redirect(home_url('log-out'));
            exit();
        } elseif ((empty($_COOKIE["user_id"])) || (empty($_COOKIE["user_role"]))) {
            if (is_user_logged_in()) {
                wp_redirect(home_url('log-out'));
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
```

Just like the other answers, I used the 'template_redirect' hook

```php
    add_action('template_redirect', 'validate_sesion');
```

I hope it can help someone

Answer (score 0):

Hook into the headers hook

`add_action( 'wp_headers', [ $this, 'forward_to_login' ] );`

```
/**
 * @return void
 */
function forward_to_login() {
    wp_redirect( 'www.example.com' );
}
```

Simple an clean.